# Exercise about CW Complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I've just started studying algebraic topology this semester and I've been given some homework to do. Right now I'm struggling with the following exercise (which has already taken me too much time):

Given integers k and l, let $X(k,l)$ be the CW complex with a single 0-cell, a single 1-cell and two 2-cells attached by maps $f, g : S^1 \to S^1$ which, respectively, wrap the circle around itself k and l times.

I've managed to prove that $X(k,1)$ is homotopy equivalent to $X(k',1)$ for $k \neq k'$. Moreover, I believe I've showed that $X(2,2)$ is Not homotopy equivalent to $X(2,1)$. My question now is:

**Is $X(2,2)$ homotopy equivalent to $X(2,0)$???** If I'm not mistaken both have the same fundamental group, so I can't use that. Also, I haven't learned homology, so that's not allowed too. The complex $X(2,0)$ is a wedge between the projective plane and $S^2$ (I believe), and $X(2,2)$ are two projective planes glued...(?) Any hints or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: after attaching the first $2$-cell using a degree $2$ map, what is the fundamental group of the resulting space? Which elements do the two possible attaching maps of the second $2$-cell represent?

Comment: Well, after attaching the first 2-cell along the map $z \mapsto z^2$ we get a complex with fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (it's a projective plane, right?). However, I'm not getting what you mean with the second question...

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now... After attaching the first 2-cell along $z \mapsto z^2$, I need to show that $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ given by $f(z)=z^2$ is homotopic to  $g: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ given by $f(z)=1$. Then the final attachments will be equivalent.